# How to punctuate a complex sentence with two quotes?

Tags: punctuation, quotations, colons

Supposing, there is a sentence:

> For example, if parents ask their son or daughter: “There are 10
>   ballerinas at the theater but all of female dancers have gone on the
>   tour. How many ballerinas remained at the theater?”, a child will
>   respond expectedly: “I do not know”.

There are two colons, which, I think, is not an idea to get away with. Could you, please, suggest proper punctuation here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a colon when there is a complete sentence before the quote.

> Parents might test their children by asking logical puzzles: "There are 10..."

When the quote is embedded in a sentence, don't use a colon. If there is an introductory phrase with "says" or "asks", use a comma.

> If parents ask their son or daughter, “There are 10..."